# How do you do a 'rest' parameter for a flow type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to be able to declare an object `type` which has some keys which are required, but then will have a variable number of extra, unknown keys (which I know the type of, but not the name of the key). Is this possible with flow?

Here's an example of how that would be used:

```
type BlahType = {
  blah: string,
  ...rest: Array<string>, // this is what I would expect to be able to do
};

const myFunction = (blah: string, ...args: Array<string>): BlahType => {
  const otherConstants = args.reduce(
    (obj, arg) => Object.assign(obj, { [arg]: arg }),
    {},
  );

  return {
    BLAH_CONSTANT: blah,
    ...otherConstants,
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for `{ blah: string, [string]: string }`?

Comment: does that allow any number of `string` typed keys with `string` typed valued? If so, that's definitely what I am looking for.

Comment: If you don't know all the props of your object just use normal subtyping. It is called [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) in Flow and the default kind of polymorphism. If you need to preserve access to the other props you can also use [bounded subtyping](https://flow.org/blog/2015/03/12/Bounded-Polymorphism/).

Answer (score 1):

Your return type would be `{ blah: string, [string]: string }`.

So you have the following code (like you can see on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBCMAhgBYAquBAvGAN6phgBGpZAXGAM4YBOASwB2AcwA0TMJIDavQaIC6XOcPGoAvgG50AYzhDeYALZYAYgFchOjAP1g6ACjbll-VWLAA6byT4jurvIi0goAlFzE5FT49gB8DJJ6BhhgcBhkeHwAwvq8JEIY3PZgvv6efHgAJuY6eA6SzA5wLABWHqWhcWAA8q141p4k3NwCIkJNrR70YNKlSiV+YOqhEszM9OqrYKHazJIVGOZ8QglrrOxbe2fenmkZ2bkY+YWSWhqae0A)):

```js
type BlahType = {
  blah: string,

  [string]: string,
};

const myFunction = (blah: string, ...args: string[]): BlahType => {
  const otherConstants = args.reduce(
    (obj, arg) => Object.assign(obj, { [arg]: arg }),
    {},
  );

  return {
    blah,

    ...otherConstants
  };
};
```